# Unable to set up Outlook with local IMAP (dovecot) host on Mac

Tags: kerberos, microsoft-outlook, mac, imap

I am trying to configure Outlook 365 (version 16.22.1) on Mac High Sierra (10.13.6). The Mac is a domain member on a Windows Active Directory domain. Our office has a self-hosted IMAP mail server running Dovecot. Dovecot works just fine with Thunderbird and A/D authentication kerberos/GSSAPI. I'm trying to set Outlook up to use the Dovecot/IMAP server.

In Outlook, when I click 'Add Account', then enter the email address, it defaults to "Exchange". Selecting 'Not Exchange' gives me a list of other providers (Google, iCloud, etc.) and an IMAP choice. The IMAP choice only provides for ID/PW authentication, no kerberos.

Going back to Exchange (even though the server is not Exchange), I have a choice of methods, 'User name and password', 'kerberos' or 'Client Certificate Authentication'. I select kerberos. I fills in my kerberos ID which, according to Microsoft, I assume is correct. It asks me for my server which is mail.hprs.local.

I then get a pop-up saying, "Outlook was redirected to the server mail.ohprs.org to get new settings for your account myname@ohprs.org. Do you want to allow this server to configure your settings?" This is NOT the server I want to use to configure my settings, so I answer 'Always deny', whereupon it fails with, "Unable to connect to the server.Please try again', and no account is created.

If instead I answer, 'Always Allow', it fails with the same message.

With Thunderbird I have a manual configure page where I could set in/out servers, ports, authentication mechanism and TLS, etc. I'm not getting that far with Outlook.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

According [this Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/outlook/kerberos-authentication-outlook-2016-for-mac), Outlook for Mac supports Kerberos protocol as a method of authentication with Microsoft Exchange Server and standalone LDAP accounts.
However, as you use Dovecot/IMAP server, I’m afraid it doesn’t support for your scenario.

With Kerberos/GSSAPI, the account would have no password. If you want to use Outlook, I think you may try to use normal IMAP protocol with Username/Password.

Comment: "With Kerberos/GSSAPI, the account would have no password. " That's correct, authentication is done via Active Directory authentication. This works just fine with Thunderbird, but apparently Outlook doesn't have a way to change server, ports or security mechanism. NTLM does not work with Dovecot. So, I guess you're right, unless someone else has a suggestion. I'll have to use user/PW, which kind of sucks since this is an Active Directory domain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like [Automx](https://automx.org/en/) to assist in autodiscover?  Outlook is going to try and find configuration from somewhere, I'm not sure how it plays with Dovecot.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will work. Automx says, "... provide is real name, mail address and password." That's basically what Outlook is doing. The problem is that this is an intra-LAN Mail Delivery Agent and the email address domain: ohprs.org is not handled by the internal MDA, so anything Outlook (or probably automx) figures out based on the email address domain will be wrong. I need is a way to override incoming and outgoing servers, ports and security so that it looks only at the local server: mail.hprs.local, not at the public server ohprs.org. Is that possible with Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to consider that this is not doable. I believe I agree with Shaw in that kerberos authentication from Outlook is intended for Exchange, no other email servers exist in the Microsoft universe. Therefore, I am reverting to the IMAP ID/PW mechanism, which is rather sad since even Thunderbird is able to do Active Directory authentication via kerberos on the Mac. Oh well.

I'm considering this issue close. As I am relatively new to this forum I am not familiar with the secret handshakes involved to mark this question as closed, nor do I see anything obvious on the page itself. So, if any reader is able and willing to do so, or would like to tell me how, please do.

Thanks All!