# How to use Outlook (New Look) on MacOS with a local dockerized Dovecot?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, docker, imap

I have a problem similar [to this other Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1408723/unable-to-set-up-outlook-with-local-imap-dovecot-host-on-mac?rq=1) about using Outlook on macOS and a local Dovecot running within its own Docker container. The [original poster on that other question self-answered](https://superuser.com/a/1410065/167207) the question by just giving up.

Did anyone solve adding an IMAP account like `user@[127.0.0.1]`?

Comment: What does “New Look” mean? The Outlook looks different? Or you want to revisit the topic?